# Codeigniter $_SERVER in config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I have what I suspect may be a really dumb question.  And if it's been answered before, please let me know.  Here is what I am attempting to do inside an old CI project in application/config/config.php circa line 287:

If an outside API request is hitting the site from a specific URL, then turn off CSRF protection.  (hacky solution I know, no proper API is built out because it is a very old project and the code is in Legacy mode)

```
if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'foo/bar') === FALSE) {
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
} else {
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_foobar';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_foobar_cookie';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

I am getting the following error message when attempting to execute this code, at odd times:

```
Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the $_SERVER be accessible inside the config folder.  Unless something happens in CI post loading of config files?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The request to the foo/bar url is being done via a cURL request, could this factor into the problem?

Comment: Can you var dump $_SERVER in there?

Comment: I cannot in production mode, but in dev mode on a subdomain and on my local machine it is populated.

Comment: And I can confirm $_SERVER is populated on a test controller FYI.

Comment: @Hammerstein the request to foo/bar is coming from a cURL request, could that factor into the problem?

Comment: cURL isn't going to make a difference. You could verify this for yourself by navigating to the url in something like fiddler and using curl with the var_dump in there to prove that the output is the same. If you search for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = in your project, what does it come up with?